# How correct catch error when i write to a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, node-modules

I have a problem with catching error in module fs exactly writeFile.

I tried to try/catch for catch error and write to logs, but it's not working.
In debbuger error don't go on catch block, and after invoke too many times, nothing happiness.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const writeData = (body) => {
    try{
        const stringData = JSON.stringify(body);
            fs.writeFile('./data76/data.json', stringData, {flag: 'a+'} ,(err) =>{
                if(!err){
                    console.log('file was writed');
                }else {
                    console.error('Error writing new data');
                    throw new Error(err);
                }
            });

    }catch(error){
        console.error('THIS ERROR!!!!!');
         let dataError = JSON.stringify(error);
         fs.open('./logs/error.log', 'wx', (err, fd) => {
             if(!err){
                 fs.writeFile(fd, dataError, (err) => {
                     if(!err){
                         fs.close(fd, (err) => {
                             if(!err){
                                 console.log('log was written success');

                     }else{
                                 console.error('file log wasn\'t closed');                                
                             }
                         });
                     }else{
                        console.error('log wasn\'t writed'); 
                     }
                 });
             }else {
                 fs.writeFile(fd, dataError, (err) => {
                     if(!err){
                         console.log('log was writed');
                     }else {
                         console.error('log wasn\'t writed');
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
    };

};

const body = {
    "name": {
        "first": "John",
        "jobtitle": "Driver"
    },
    "uuid_company": "ab667468-d7c5-469e-b402-0bd2d71073fa",
    "license_number": "AB58659",
    "phone": "+19019876512",
    "uuid": "08475753",
    "place_id": "place_not_matter",
    "birthday": "10.12.1967"
};

writeData(body);
```

In result, I waiting for catch error and write it in a file.
My personal logger

Comment: You can't use `try`/`catch` for asynchronously thrown exceptions, like those in your `writeFile` callback. (You can if you use promises and `await`). Don't throw an error, just put the error handling code in that `else` block and drop the `try`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try/catch` outside of await/promises cannot catch errors throw inside of asynchronous callbacks.  So, if you're trying to handle an error inside the callback for an `fs.writeFile()`, you need to insert the error handling code inside the `fs.writeFile()` callback or (better yet) use the promise versions of file handling and let errors propagate through promises.

In addition, most errors writing to a file are not transient errors.  So, it would be rare that trying to write again will actually be a solution and not just encounter the same issue.  More typical errors are disk full, media error, volume not responding, etc...  Those are unlikely to suddenly work by just trying again.  Also, each particular type of error may need a different strategy to deal with.  Is there a particular type of error you've encountered that you want to devise a strategy for?

Also, `fs.writeFile()` will take the file path directly and then it will handle the `fs.open()` and `fs.close()` for you.  You don't need to manually open it, write to it and close it.

Comment: @IlyaRogatkin - You can't throw up from an asynchronous callback except when using promises.  Remember, the top level function has already returned at the point the asynchronous callback is called.  When you throw from that callback, all it does is go back into the file system platform code somewhere and do nothing. You can't catch exceptions at a higher level when thrown from an asynchronous callback.

Comment: I can use writeFileSync - or it's not best practices in node.js?

Comment: @IlyaRogatkin - `fswriteFileSync()` should only ever be used at startup/initialization or in some single user script (that never has multiple requests from multiple users).  So, in a server, you would only ever use it at server initialization time and never during a request handler.  Because node.js runs your Javascript single threaded and `fs.writeFileSync()` blocks that one thread, it would ruin your server scalability.